# How to clean unnecessary full text user queue items in dm_queue_item table in Documenutm 7.1/16.4 and Xplore 1.6?

Tags: documentum, documentum7.3

I have faced an issue where my environment's Index agent was NOT able to process new documents. While checking I fond out that dmi_queue_item cont is very high, so I am posting this self answered question which will let us know how to get your queue items cleaned up with Xplore OLD items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clear the unwanted queue items , we will have to perform following steps

1. Stop the Services for XPlore and CS
2. Backup the items that are not index user

```
create table temp_dmi_queue_item_s as (select * from dmi_queue_item_s where name <> 'dm_fulltext_index_user' AND name <> 'dm_fulltext_index_user_01' );
```

3. Truncate table

```
truncate table dmi_queue_item_s;
```

3. Restore the items that are not index user

```
insert into dmi_queue_item_s select * from temp_dmi_queue_item_s;
```

4)Run ftintegrity in order to fix any inconsistencies between Repository and Index data

5. Start the Services and add the test document, check if its getting queued for indexing

Note- Make sure, implementation of the above steps should be tested on non-production environment before production